# how can i solve provide error causing by dagger-hilt?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, dagger-hilt, clean-architecture

I'm using kotlin clean architecture + hilt in my project.
this the error i got :

```
    C:\Users\ayoub\AndroidStudioProjects\cleanArchitecture_project\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\com\example\cleanarchitecture_project\presentation\App_HiltComponents.java:122: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.example.cleanarchitecture_project.domain.repository.UserRepository cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
  public abstract static class SingletonC implements App_GeneratedInjector,
                         ^
      com.example.cleanarchitecture_project.domain.repository.UserRepository is injected at
          com.example.cleanarchitecture_project.domain.UseCase(repository)
      com.example.cleanarchitecture_project.domain.UseCase is injected at
          com.example.cleanarchitecture_project.presentation.UserViewModel(useCase)
      com.example.cleanarchitecture_project.presentation.UserViewModel is injected at
          com.example.cleanarchitecture_project.presentation.UserViewModel_HiltModules.BindsModule.binds(vm)
      @dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelMap java.util.Map<java.lang.String,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>> is requested at
          dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.ViewModelFactoriesEntryPoint.getHiltViewModelMap() [com.example.cleanarchitecture_project.presentation.App_HiltComponents.SingletonC ? com.example.cleanarchitecture_project.presentation.App_HiltComponents.ActivityRetainedC ? com.example.cleanarchitecture_project.presentation.App_HiltComponents.ViewModelC]
```

that's the link of the project in bitbucket :
[Here](https://bitbucket.org/ayoubbelmaati/cleanarchi_kotlin/src/master/)

thanks for helping me.

Comment: Could you pls add the related class file codes here e.g. view model that is using this userRepository etc

Answer (score 0):

Add @Singleton annotation and @Inject constructor to UserRepository

```
@Singleton
class UserRepository @Inject constructor(private val userDao: UserDao) {
...
}
```

Comment: it's still not working for me.

Comment: You may need to clean and rebuild the project